# touch move works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my html page. I want to deactivate touch move in all page except for a div in which I want scrolling. So I add this js code:

`document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'rest_comm') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};`

It does not always work.

I found with Oscar Paz's help that the problem is that the scrolling div has a lot of divs inside. So how can I deactivate touch move in whole page except for the scrolling div and all its included divs.

Comment: If only thing that is visible in screen after scroll is this div (rest_comm) of course it prevents scrolling regardless what you do..

Comment: This div is only 50% of the page's height. So it is not only this visible after scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that e.target won't always be your scrolling div. If you've got elements inside it, e.target is the deepest element in the DOM tree you touched (it could be a paragraph, an image ...).
What you've got to do is to check whether e.target is inside your scrolling div, or is your scrolling div. Basically:

```
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
       var node = e.target;
       while (node && node.id != 'comm_list_content') node = node.parentElement;
       if (!node) e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

This way you'll only call preventDefault() if you touch outside your div.

Comment: I have a lot of divs inside my scrolling div. I tried it as you post it but it does not work.

Comment: Can you tell me if there is any error? I don't have a touch device here to test it, but this is the idea (I've used this technique before). Maybe you could post a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Sorry id 'rest_comm' is from another html page. In this page the scrolling div is comm_list_content.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer and this time I think it should work.